# Microcontroller requirements to implement an embedded web server with using websocket, JS, and HTML5

Tags: websocket, embedded, webserver, stm32, microcontroller

I'm developing a new product, and one of the design requirements is to implement an embedded web server on the microcontroller.
The web pages should be responsive and dynamic like single page application (SPA) web pages and there are 3 pages to be implemented with light images and graphics.

I plan to pick out a microcontroller from the STM32 range, and my questions are related to the hardware design part :

1. what are the minimum Microcontroller requirements to implement an embedded web server in terms of performance and memory?
2. what is the approximate size of the used memory for the lwIP stack, web server, and client-side code?
3. where to store the webpages? internal Flash, ROM, External Flash?
4. And finally, what is the complexity level of the implementation in comparison to the traditional HTTP request?

Thanks,

Comment: google stm32 webserver. Plenty examples, pages, tutorials, YT videos ....   What was your research effort? IMO none. Of course, forget about server-side JS

Answer (score 1):

1. Network connectivity and sufficient RAM+Flash to run your server. If using TLS (i.e. HTTPS), some processing power (preferably a crypto accelerator) will come in handy.
2. Depends on what you're planning to serve :) Let's assume a single concurrent client connection and a web server serving simple dynamic pages implemented in C. You'll want at around 100-200 KiB of RAM for the network and HTTP server - maybe much more if doing anything non-trivial. Add around 50-100 KiB more for TLS. This will be enough to implement a few simple text-based config and status pages. As for the amount of Flash (code memory), depends on how much code you write and how big your web assets are :) Note that TLS libraries are rather large, perhaps around 300-500 KiB. These estimates don't include any server-side scripting languages (javascript, python, ...) - C only.
3. Unless you have specific requirements, your web assets should be few, small and fit (as text or binary blobs) into the same Flash as everything else.
4. It's more complex. Depends on what you compare it with. It's not like you're going to implement the HTTP protocol yourself - find a library for that. But almost nothing is free in a microcontroller environment. You manage your own memory, your own threads, your own everything.

Comment: 2. Comple overestimate. I have everything, WEB, SSL, LWIP, USBH, USBD + plenty more on 128k RAM uC running RTOS.

Comment: Depends. Certainly it's possible to squeeze stuff into smaller systems if you put effort into it. For a newbie it's easier to have a bit of resources to burn than optimize the hell out of it.